# Running android application on windows, developed on linux

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android development.

I want to run an Android application on Windows using eclipse that has been already developed on Linux OS. I tried to copy the source/res and menifest file of Android application form linux and started creating a new project on windows. I tried to replace the source/res and menifest of newly created Project on windows with one on linux. It was unable to generate R.java file.

I wonder if java is portable accross platform then why I couldn't create and compile a new project on Windows from Linux.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Running Android apps has nothing to do with what plattform you developed the code on. Your question is really about 'how to set up an Android project with Eclipse?'. Java's portability here isn't even an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is portable, I've succesfully tried it.  Try to go to clean the project (Project > Clean...), to force Eclipse to regenerate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily port a Linux's Project into Window's Eclipse. All you need to do is

- Just copy project folder from linux pc to windows pc.
- Now import Project in eclipse from File Menu.
- Once successful import is finish, goto folder there will be a file called **.classpath** in hidden manner, right click on that file and remove "read only" attribute.
- Come to eclipse again and clean the project with "build automatic" option.
- Your project is read to work in Windows environment.